# How to speed up language-tool-python library use case

Tags: python, python-multithreading, languagetool

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 million rows of social media comments. I'm using the [language-tool-python](https://pypi.org/project/language-tool-python/) library to find the number of grammatical errors in a comment. Afaik the language-tool library by default sets up a local language-tool server on your machine and queries responses from that.

Getting the number of grammatical errors is just consists of creating an instance of the language tool object and calling the `.check()` method with the string you want to check as a parameter.

```
>>> tool = language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-US')
>>> text = 'A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker’s Guide tot he Galaxy'
>>> matches = tool.check(text)
>>> len(matches)
2
```

So the method I used is `df['body_num_errors'] = df['body'].apply(lambda row: len(tool.check(row)))`. Now I am pretty sure this works. Its quite straight forward. This single line of code has been running for the past hour.

<s>Because running the above example took 10-20 second</s>, so with 3 million instances, it might as well take virtually forever.

Is there any way I can cut my losses and speed this process up? Would iterating over every row and putting the whole thing inside of a [threadpoolexecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) help? Intuitively it makes sense to me as its a I/O bound task.

I am open to any suggestions as to how to speed up this process and if the above method works would appreciate if someone can show me some sample code.

edit - Correction.

It takes 10-20 seconds along with the instantiation, calling the method is almost instantaneous.

Comment: maybe first try to use `threadpoolexecutor`. And sample code you have even in your link.

Comment: Does only `tool.check` take 10-20 seconds, or does that include instantiating the `LanguageTool`?

Comment: @furas I am estimating it would take around multiple days as it stands now, with threading if it works, it might take hours, I don't want to commit to a solution, before I can be fairly confident it would work. For I can't tell if it would finish or not before a long time.

Comment: we can't say if it will work in your situation - you have to run code to test it.

Comment: @roland-smith, My bad, It takes 10-20 seconds with the instantiation, calling the method is almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the creator of `language_tool_python`. First, none of the comments here make sense. The bottleneck is in `tool.check()`; there is nothing slow about using `pd.DataFrame.map()`.

LanguageTool is running on a local server on your machine. There are at least two major ways to speed this up:

##### Method 1: Initialize multiple servers

```py
servers = []
for i in range(100):
  servers.append(language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-US'))
```

Then call to each server from a different thread. Or alternatively initialize each server within its own thread.

##### Method 2: Increase the thread count

LanguageTool takes a `maxCheckThreads` option – see the LT [HTTPServerConfig](https://languagetool.org/development/api/org/languagetool/server/HTTPServerConfig.html) documentation – so you could also try playing around with that? From a glance at LanguageTool's source code, it looks like the [default number of threads in a single LanguageTool server](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/blob/master/languagetool-server/src/main/java/org/languagetool/server/HTTPServerConfig.java#L74) is 10.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation, we can see that `language-tool-python` has the configuration option `maxSpellingSuggestions`.

However, despite the name of the variable and the default value being `0`, I have noticed that the code runs noticeably faster (almost 2 times faster) when this parameter is actually set to `1`.

I don't know where this discrepancy comes from, and the documentation does not mention anything specific about the default behavior. It is a fact however that (at least for my own dataset, which I don't think can affect this much the running time) this setting improves the performance.

Example initialization:

```
import language_tool_python

language_tool = language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-US', config={'maxSpellingSuggestions': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about scaling up with pandas, switch to Dask instead. It integrates with Pandas and will use multiple cores in your CPU, which I am assuming you have, instead of a single-core that pandas use. This helps parallelize the 3 million instances and can speed up your execution time. You can read more about dask [here](https://dask.org/) or see an example [here](https://medium.com/featurepreneur/pandas-vs-dask-the-power-of-parallel-computing-994a202a74bd#:%7E:text=Reading%20a%20data%20frame%20is,and%20then%20it%20is%20processed.).

Comment: In this specific use case parallelization is not as straightforward as using a processpool or a third party package to do that for you because every iteration of .apply() makes a request to the server, and dask backend defaults to single core when this happens or throws an error. However, there are workarounds around that, so parallelization is the answer.

Comment: What did you end up doing to solve the error?

Comment: since parallization was too much work for what its worth I used the numpy [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) feature, the pandas .apply() function is a for loop in the backend so its not the fastest.

Comment: @FardinAhsan always a good idea to use numpy whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to create an instance "instance of the language tool" once.
Then for each row, call method "or function depending on your code pattern" that includes the rest of the code logic

```
 matches = tool.check(text)
 len(matches)
```